# Why when allocating small sizes of memory incrementally I see only one mapped area using pmap?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

The question is very long to fit in the title indeed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t sz = atol(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        char *arr = malloc(sz);
        printf("allocated %ld bytes (%d)\n", sz, i);
    }
}
```

This program allocates memory incrementally forever. The size of memory to allocate on each iteration is provided in `argv[1]`.

When I pass a small value like `10240`, letting the program run for a while, the output of `pmap` looks like this:

```
18616:   ./alloc_program 10240
0000561614c00000      4K r---- alloc_program
0000561614c01000      4K r-x-- alloc_program
0000561614c02000      4K r---- alloc_program
0000561614c03000      4K r---- alloc_program
0000561614c04000      4K rw--- alloc_program
0000561616488000 3658600K rw---   [ anon ]     <----- here, only one mapping
00007fbad85ff000    148K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007fbad8624000   1504K r-x-- libc-2.31.so
00007fbad879c000    296K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007fbad87e6000      4K ----- libc-2.31.so
00007fbad87e7000     12K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007fbad87ea000     12K rw--- libc-2.31.so
00007fbad87ed000     24K rw---   [ anon ]
00007fbad8802000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007fbad8803000    140K r-x-- ld-2.31.so
00007fbad8826000     32K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007fbad882f000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007fbad8830000      4K rw--- ld-2.31.so
00007fbad8831000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffee93da000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffee93fb000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffee93fe000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K --x--   [ anon ]
 total          3660960K
```

When providing a relatively big number like `1024000`, I get this output:

```
3348:   ./alloc_program 1024000
0000561680979000      4K r---- alloc_program
000056168097a000      4K r-x-- alloc_program
000056168097b000      4K r---- alloc_program
000056168097c000      4K r---- alloc_program
000056168097d000      4K rw--- alloc_program
0000561682936000    132K rw---   [ anon ]    ---------> the number 132 is consistent
00007f31aeac7000 19405312K rw---   [ anon ]  ---------> these two mappings
00007f364f147000    148K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f364f16c000   1504K r-x-- libc-2.31.so
00007f364f2e4000    296K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f364f32e000      4K ----- libc-2.31.so
00007f364f32f000     12K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f364f332000     12K rw--- libc-2.31.so
00007f364f335000     24K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f364f34a000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f364f34b000    140K r-x-- ld-2.31.so
00007f364f36e000     32K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f364f377000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f364f378000      4K rw--- ld-2.31.so
00007f364f379000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007fff203b9000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007fff203e5000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007fff203e8000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K --x--   [ anon ]
 total         19407804K
```

I've noticed that the number `132` is consistent and shows most of the times unless I allocate really really big amount of memory, in this case, I get something like this:

```
2354:   ./alloc_program 1024000
000056050a96c000      4K r---- alloc_program
000056050a96d000      4K r-x-- alloc_program
000056050a96e000      4K r---- alloc_program
000056050a96f000      4K r---- alloc_program
000056050a970000      4K rw--- alloc_program
000056050beff000 54833988K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f5aa6aed000 65798144K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6a56aed000    148K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f6a56b12000   1504K r-x-- libc-2.31.so
00007f6a56c8a000    296K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f6a56cd4000      4K ----- libc-2.31.so
00007f6a56cd5000     12K r---- libc-2.31.so
00007f6a56cd8000     12K rw--- libc-2.31.so
00007f6a56cdb000     24K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6a56cf0000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f6a56cf1000    140K r-x-- ld-2.31.so
00007f6a56d14000     32K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f6a56d1d000      4K r---- ld-2.31.so
00007f6a56d1e000      4K rw--- ld-2.31.so
00007f6a56d1f000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffd3e536000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffd3e55e000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffd3e561000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K --x--   [ anon ]
 total        120634492K
```

1 - What is happening under the hood? When do I get one mapping and when do I get two?

2 - What is this `132K` area holding? What's special about that number?

3 - As you may see from the last run of `pmap`, the number of mappings doesn't exceed two mappings, why?

4 - Also, you may notice that the `pid` of the program on the three runs are decreasing, that's because I had to reboot the machine each time I run the program for a while, when letting the program run for a while, the OS (I'm using linux) freezes and doesn't respond even to the shutdown signals... Why is the OS allowing any program to allocate all that much of memory that will eventually miss up the OS? Why not only allow allocation to a certain extent that keeps the OS functioning perfectly?

Comment: For 1-3, keywords "sbrk versus mmap".

Comment: 4 is really a separate question and doesn't belong in the same post.  A common cause of this is that you are using swap space, which does in theory allow the system to keep operating, even if it's so slow that it's of no practical use.  It's assumed that if you configured swap space, this is the behavior you wanted.  If you'd rather have the system keep running fast and your programs die, disable swap (and maybe also overcommit)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the help. I can't seem to figure out why this question is a duplicate. The linked question is asking for a different thing. What's in this question that makes it a duplicate?